# update data frame with another data frame only if the column contains specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames df1, df2.

I want to update the df1 with value "yes" in the same row number and column number as it is in the df2,

I have attached the image for your reference.

I am using python and pandas.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `where` and `combine_first`

```
df3=df2.where(df2=='Yes').combine_first(df1)
```